# Order-only app dependencies in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have an application that depends on one of two other applications - that is, a configuration parameter in my application specifies which one it expects to be running.  In order to avoid relying on the order of lines in my `reltool.config`, I'd like to be able to specify an order-only dependency, so that if the depended-on application is present in the release it's loaded and started before my application, but if it's not there, it's just ignored.

Is that possible?  Or is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the feature is still under development to remove some bugs in execution behaviour.

See [here](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-bugs/2012-January/002741.html) for a description of the problem and [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.erlang.bugs/2770) for the original blog post by Ulf Wiger.

If you need further information, please let me know.